# Inspect opens an empty window in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Hello I'm developing Ionic-3 Hybrid application.I am inspect app on samsung J7 device with chrome remote device inspect and everything was good but unfortunatly i'm stuck When clicking "inspect" next to the url of the page open on the google chrome an empty window shows up and nothing happens.
google chrome version:

> Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit)

google chrome empty window image is below.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just update my Chrome to version  65.0.3325.162 and it works.

Answer (score 1):

if your browser not show anything after update
open **chrome://appcache-internals/** and clear the manifest cache , then reload the resource